# NameError: name 'root' is not defined trying to click on menubar

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I will try to be concrete, When I tried to click on the 'New' option menubar it is give me an error saying that the  root it is not defined, any help why it is happening that?:

> file.py", line 6, in newfile
>       root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Libraries/Document",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("lre
>   files","*.lre"),("all files","*.*"))) NameError: name 'root' is not
>   defined

I have two file in one I have this code file.py:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def newfile():
    print('hello')
    root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Libraries/Document",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("lre files","*.lre"),("all files","*.*")))
    print (root.filename)
```

And part of the other is this menu:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import library.file as New

def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()

root = Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
root.title("Interactive Toys")
menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=New.newfile)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because as far as file.py is concerned, `root` *isn't* defined.  With such a setup you'll likely want to pass the root to the newfile function (e.g. `def newfile(root):` and `filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=lambda: New.newfile(root))`.  That being said, there are a lot of other changes that could make this easier (e.g. use a class instance to keep track of your UI elements and decouple UI from application code like creating a file)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that help much ...